# Pandas dataframe to Orange table with setting role (feature or target)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, orange

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c"], "B": ["d", "e", "f"], "C": ["yes", "no", "yes"]})
```

I would like to convert df to orange table and set A and B as categorical attributes and then set C as the class variable (target variable).  Currently, I can convert to a pandas dataframe using

```
from Orange.data.pandas_compat import table_from_frame
orange_table = table_from_frame(df)
```

It converts df successfully to an orange table but I could not set the role for each column.  May I have your suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply output the Orange table from the Python Script widget.

```py
out_data=orange_table
```

Then use the **Select Column** widget to select the features and target variable.

[image: orange select column widget example]